# How to bring app to foreground in flutter integration test

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I have an integration test which taps a text of phone number, then it opens the phone dial app which makes my app put to background.

```
final firstNumber = find.byWidgetPredicate(
      (widget) => widget is RichText && tapTextSpan(widget, '09123456789'));
await tester.tap(firstNumber);
```

After `tester.tap()` it successfully open the built in dial app in phone.
How can I bring my app to foreground?

Package used: `integration_test`, `flutter_test`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flutter_foreground_task** package

use `FlutterForegroundTask.minimizeApp()` for app to background

and `FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp()` for app to foreground

that's all. I hope it helps.